# After running a LINQ over an Entity the SaveChanges method throw an Exception

Tags: linq, collections, entity-framework-5

This is my class

```
public class Employee
{
     public virtual List<Salary> Salaries { get; set; }
     public bool CanAddSalary(Salary salary)
     {
          var count = (from x in Salaries where x.Month == salary.Month
                           && x.Year == salary.Year select x).Count();
          return count == 0;
     }
     public void AddSalary(Salary salary)
     {
          if(CanAddSalary(salary))
          {
              Salaries.Add(salary);
          }
     }
}
```

1. Entity Framework loads Employee with Salaries properties.
2. CanAddSalary method just check to avoid duplicates (Nothing modified the Salaries Collection right?).
3. If CanAddSalary return true then I call AddSalary method.
4. I call Entity Framework Context.SaveChanges() and throw me and exception.

Comment: please reframe the wordings, its confusing.

Comment: What exception do you get?

Comment: The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.

Comment: Are you sure what you've outlined is the **only** thing executing, that kind of exception often comes when you're removing something from a collection but the relationship isn't set to cascade deletes or the foreign key is non nullable. So the object that has been 'removed' would be left in the db with a NULL foreign key to the object with the 'collection' - your db wouldn't be 'consistent' so EF throws the exception. Answer - mark foreign key as Nullable OR set cascade deletes OR add the 'child' to another 'collection' thereby setting the foreign key to a new value rather than null

Comment: (Ran out of chars) .. exactly which option you choose depends on what else is running, the code (on it's own) shown above **cannot** produce the exception you're describing.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `==` instead of `=` in your return statement, because otherwise you'll always get `false` from `CanAddSalary` method:

```
 public bool CanAddSalary(Salary salary)
 {
      var count = (from x in Salaries where x.Month == salary.Month
                       && x.Year == salary.Year select x).Count();
      return count == 0;
 }
```

Comment: In real code is fine, here I made some mistakes when typing. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Your Salaries should really be

```
ICollection<Salary>
```

and doing an Any() will be faster than doing a Count()

Your

```
return count = 0;
```

is wrong which means

```
Salaries.Add(salary);
```

is adding a salary that is already in the Salaries collection, that's probably the exception

Try this, if you're still getting the exception, then post that on here too so we can see the error

cheers
Stu

```
public class Employee
{
 public virtual ICollection<Salary> Salaries { get; set; }
 public bool CanAddSalary(Salary salary)
 {
      return !(from x in Salaries where x.Month == salary.Month
                       && x.Year == salary.Year select x).Any();
 }
 public void AddSalary(Salary salary)
 {
      if(CanAddSalary(salary))
      {
          Salaries.Add(salary);
      }
 }
}
```

Comment: did you change to "return !(from x in Salaries where x.Month == salary.Month
                       && x.Year == salary.Year select x).Any();"  - That's the most important bit ;-)